# Installing Windows on KVM with LVM disk

Tags: windows, kvm-virtualization, lvm

I am trying to install a windows server 2012 on a KVM. The host system is Ubuntu Server 14.04. I would like to use a logical volume, say /dev/VG/win, as main device for the guest system. However, the installation process stops at the point where I choose the drive. No drive is found and I am asked to choose a (signed) driver. I tried several driver images but have found none so far that works.
If I use an image file for the guest system, everything works fine.

This is the device part of my kvm configuration:

```
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-1.0'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
    <bootmenu enable='yes'/>
  </os>
  ...
 <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm-spice</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/data/virtio-win-0.1.102.iso'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='0' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/dara/Win.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
      <address type='drive' controller='0' bus='1' target='0' unit='0'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='block' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source dev='/dev/VG/win'/>
      <target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x07' function='0x0'/>
    </disk>
    ...
```

I tried a few variations (with virt-manager and virt-install) with no success. Is there a way to define the LVM volume, so that windows recognizes it? Or where do I get working drivers?

**Edit**:
I methodically tried every combination of drive type (bus, etc configuration by virt-manager) and driver ([here](https://launchpad.net/kvm-guest-drivers-windows/+download) and fedora link posted below), none has worked. The only bit of success was that for virtio, the drive appeared in the Choose driver dialog and the viostor driver (from fedora link) was accepted. However, the disk still does not appear in the installation dialog itself. I changed the conf excerpt above accordingly.

Comment: Don't use IDE disks. Change them to virtio and then [do the installation](http://serverfault.com/a/703676/126632).

Answer (score 1):

You could try with `<target dev='sda' bus='scsi'/>` (removing the controller reference) and see if the disk appears during the installation.
The best configuration would be `<target dev='vda' bus='virtio'/>`, but for that you would need the [virtio drivers](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/stable-virtio/virtio-win.iso) from Fedora; see also https://serverfault.com/a/650681/100793 .

Comment: If I choose scsi, the disk does not even appear in Choose driver.

Answer (score 0):

Since I tried what felt like 50 million installs, I used the following workaround:

1. create an image file and put one single NTFS partition on it (to prevent windows from creating its boot partition)
2. install windows on img file
3. add LVM drive to KVM and install fedora drivers in windows
4. shutudown and 'dd' image partition to LVM
5. remove image file from KVM, boot from LVM and be happy